# Highcharts: Symbol markers for dynamic data?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using a line chart (I think) for my data, and I'm trying to have red, yellow or green dots based upon the value of the data. The problem is, I can't even change the symbols used on the graph!
I'm using data pulled from a database, so I can't simply define the data within a series[] and then define the symbol from there, it's added using the chart.addSeries() function.

I'm sorry if this is a total noob question, I'm a total noob when it comes to JavaScript and Highcharts.

EDIT: For security reasons, I can't post the code.

Comment: Can you at least give the format of your data object you are adding in `chart.addSeries()`? What have you tried?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. I have no idea what it is, as the project is so huge I've not had time to get to grips with it. I've tried using update(), but that just causes everything to break.

Comment: Well, without sample data format or code these are just shots in the dark. You can try `chart.events.load` to hook in and loop through your data series and modify the marker.

Comment: If you cannot post the exact code, can you create a jsfiddle with something similiar that shows the problem that you have?

Comment: Let's try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lbhgk1ah/

Comment: In that jsFiddle what does `results` look like? You will most likely have to iterate over `results` to parse out the `series.data` and based on the values assign different marker/color to points as needed.

Comment: That's the part I'm having trouble with; assigning markers and colours. How would I do that? I tried using update() but it breaks everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer may not be 100% accurate, but I would do something like this:

```
// Loop over series and populate chart data
$.each(results.series, function (i, result) {
    var series = chart.get(result.id);
    //I think I have to do some sort of marker: set here

    $.each(result.data, function (i, point) {
        var x = point.x, // OR point[0]
            y = point.y; // OR point[1]
        result.data[i] = {
            color: y > 100 ? 'red' : 'blue',
            x: x,
            y: y
        }
    });

    if (series) {
        series.update(result, false);
    } else {
        chart.addSeries(result, false);
    }
});
chart.redraw();
```

As you can see, here I am adding `color` property to the point. Right now there is simple logic (value < 100), but you can apply there anything you want to, for example function which will return correct color etc.

Note that I am extracting `x` and `y` values. How to get them depends on how your data is formatted. It can be `{x: some_valueX, y: some_valueY}` or `[some_valueX, some_valueY]` or even `some_valueY` only.

**Important**: if you have a lot of points (1000+), don't forget to increase `turboThreshold` or disable it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! With a little bit of fiddling (you used i twice in there, which causes some unpleasantness), this almost works. But for some reason, the zoom shows the last 30 years (instead of just the last week), and the lines on the graph completely disappear. The points also do not change colour, even when fulfilling the statement.

Comment: Sorry for the double post, but I'm so confused on a slightly tangential matter; why does calling update on a point (even with no parameters) break the chart?

Comment: I am sorry - what I used twice there? Hard to say what is wrong. Maybe you have different data format? Or you didn't change `turboThreshold`. Regarding update of the points - maybe it's connected to the `dataGrouping` - have you tried to disable that option? You can not update grouped points.

Comment: The variable i was used twice in there; once in results.series, once in result.data, which caused some weirdness to happen. After correcting that and a little fiddling, it seems to work pretty well now! Thanks for the answer.